# How to add a file out of project to composer classmap autoload?

Tags: php, composer-php

Here is the structure of my project

```
mainProject
 ┃
 ┣ subProject1
 ┃ ┃
 ┃ ┗ composer.json
 ┃
 ┗ subProject2
   ┃
   ┗ classINeed.php
```

My `composer.json`

```bash
{
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": ["../subProject2/classINeed.php"]
  }
}
```

Command `composer dump-autoload` doesn't return any error but `subProject1/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` doesn't have the expected `classINeed.php`

Is it possible to add an **out of project** file to [composer autoload classmap](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap) ?

Comment: Is that `classINeed` namespaced? Did you checked all of generated files? Maybe it's somewhere else?

Comment: I would do several autoloads, one in the root and others in the sub folders. So in the root and we call the others autoload

Comment: @Justinas - Yes the class is namespaced, and the file should be in autoload_classmap.php in my understanding

Comment: @BrunoMorais that's what hakre is suggesting too, If it's the only way I'll try to add composer to subProject2 then

Answer (score 0):

> ```json
> {
>   "autoload": {
>     "classmap": ["../subProject2/classINeed.php"]
>   }
> }
> ```

> Is it possible to add an out of project file to composer autoload classmap ?

Yes, to get an out of project file into Composer autoload classmap you define it out of project (that is within its own project), have it in its own autoloader and then require the other project.

You then have it in there.

`subProject1/composer.json`

```json
{
  "name": "main/sub-1",
  "require": {
    "main/sub-2": "1.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
      "@php -r 'require __DIR__ . \"/vendor/autoload.php\"; var_dump(class_exists(\"Foo\"));'"
    ]
  },
  "repositories": {
    "main/sub-2": {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "../subProject2",
      "options": {
        "versions": {
          "main/sub-2": "1.0.0"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`subProject2/composer.json`

```json
{
  "name": "main/sub-2",
  "description": "File I need",
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": ["classINeed.php"]
  }
}
```

Then run in `subProject1`:

```bash
$ rm -rf vendor && composer install
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing main/sub-2 (1.0.0): Symlinking from ../subProject2
Generating autoload files
> @php -r 'require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php"; var_dump(class_exists("Foo"));'
Command line code:1:
bool(true)
```

---

> Thanks a lot for your answer but sadly I don't have composer in subProject2

In this case - while not recommended - it is certainly possible to provide that composer.json for the path but within the first project.

Therefore the other project must not have a composer.json. This is the `package` repository.

Here an extended variant that shows it in addition:

`subProject1/composer.json` (`subProject2/no-composer-json` has *no* `composer.json` file)

```
{
  "name": "main/sub-1",
  "require": {
    "main/sub-2-no-composer-json": "1.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
      "# this time autoloader test with composer only",
      "classINeed::hasMagic__callStatic"
    ]
  },
  "repositories": {
    "packagist.org": false,
    "main/sub-2": {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "../subProject2",
      "options": {
        "versions": {
          "main/sub-2": "1.0.0"
        }
      }
    },
    "main/sub-2-no-composer-json": {
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
        "name": "main/sub-2-no-composer-json",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "dist": {
          "type": "path",
          "url": "../subProject2/no-composer-json"
        },
        "autoload": {
          "classmap": ["classINeed.php"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Exemplary run:

```
$ composer install
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating autoload files
> # this time autoloader test with composer only
> classINeed::hasMagic__callStatic
{
    "name": "hasMagic__callStatic",
    "argv": [
        "object Event: post-autoload-dump"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but sadly I don't have composer in subProject2

Comment: You don't need to. Instead of creating the composer.json there, you can define it in a package repository in the composer.json in the subproject-1. I extend the answer to give an example.

Answer (score 0):

Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::[addClassMap()](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/main/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.php#L151)

```php
$loader = require PROJECT_DIR . '/vendor/autoload.php';
var_dump($loader->getClassMap());
$loader->addClassMap(['MyClass' => '/path/to/class.php']);
var_dump(new MyClass());
```