# Composer get dev-branch without changing version in require

Tags: git, composer-php

I have this in composer.json:

```
...
"require": {
      ...
      "some/bundle": "^5.0",
},
"repositories": [{
      "type": "git",
      "url": "git@github.com:some/bundle"
}],
...
```

I can do `some/bundle": "dev-branch"` to get the branch as version, but I don't want to do it that way.

I don't want to change the version number in `"require"` instead I just want to use the dev-branch.

I can do:

```
"repositories": [{
      "type": "git",
      "url": "git@github.com:some/bundle",
      "branch": "dev-branch"
}],
```

**but it doesn't work.**

How can I do that ? Thanks.

Comment: What is your intention? Do you want to install the package for local development?

Answer (score 0):

**This is not possible. (maybe in future)**

Comment: As unspecific as your question is, it certainly does not appear possible to you (as much not possible as you don't want it to be). Apart from that there is a plethora of options in Composer, be it _Aliases_, _`replace`_ or by just specifying the package version for the repository as you define it even in the same configuration file (compare: _package repository_ in [answer to _How to add a file out of project to composer classmap autoload?_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72718867/367456)).